# Declaring new variables on the fly?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

Has anyone found a way to declare variables on the fly?

I have some variables that can be limitless...

```
val1
val2
val3
val4...
```

Is there a way to create these on the fly, something like...

```
for(loop though){
  val + '1' = dosomething('1') 
}
```

I know it wont look anything like the above, but hoping you get the gist of it.

Comment: I'm confused by your comments on the two answers below, since maps and lists can easily be passed to a VF page...can you elaborate on your use case that would prevent you from using them?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible in apex. You could however use a list:

```
List<String> values = new List<String>();

for (Integer i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++) {
    values.add(dosomething(i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, this is a good workaround, but it won't work in my situation as i need to pass the values to the visualforce page. many thanks

Comment: A Visualforce page can still accept collection classes like Jeremy's `List` or eyescream's `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

Apex is a compiled, not parsed / dynamic language. You could pull such thing off in say Javascript or PHP but (as far as I know) not in Java. And when you get to the bottom of it - Salesforce is built on Oracle database and Java so Apex is kind of thin wrapper on Java calls they deemed most necessary.

Just out of curiosity - why would you need that?

Use Jeremy's idea with loops if you need sequential access. Or...

If you need "unique key -> some value", use Maps.

```
Map<String, Double> myMap = new Map<String, Double>();
for(Integer i = 1; i < 10; ++i){
    myMap.put('someKey' + String.valueOf(i),Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
}
System.debug(myMap);
System.debug(myMap.get('someKey7'));
```

The "double" in this example can be equally Integer, Id, Account, MyCustomClass... whatever your function returns.

There's one more trick I can think of that might be helpful if your data comes from external source. It's to use JSON / XML parsers that could cast any kind of data (held in a String) to a collection of your choice. It kind of goes back to List/Map idea but it's totally up to you how would you build / retrieve this string beforehand. Read about [JSON methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_json.htm) for a start although if you don't have a structure that follows predictable pattern you might want to check out JSON/XML parsers ([click here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_jsonparser.htm) and scroll down to the examples).

Comment: Hreat info, and your work around is quite brilliant, I will remember this method. However it doesn't work for my situation, as the variable needs to be passed to the visualforce page, so I will still need to create the variable. But I'm sure someone else will find this very interesting, much appreciated.

Comment: Maps / lists can be used in Visualforce too, `{!myMap['someKey1']}`. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_maps_lists.htm. Just remember about the 1000 items limit (10 000 if your page has `readOnly=true`).